# Set Error cause in JavaScript (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception

is it possible to specify the cause of an Error in JavaScript (node.js)? I found the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) which defines how to set the message / file / line but not the cause of an error.

The reason I'm interested in this is that I want to catch an internal error and propagate it to the surface in a nested exception (similar to exception chaining in Java).

Edit: I just found the following answer on stackoverflow on [how to chain exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886769/how-to-chain-exceptions-in-javascript-ie-add-cause-like-in-java). Is that really all you can do?

-- ooxi

Comment: I have the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25763837/535203

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify a "caused by" in a JavaScript Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763837/how-to-specify-a-caused-by-in-a-javascript-error)

Comment: @FranklinYu please keep in mind that the question you are referring to was ask several months after this one

Comment: Node.js now supports adding specific cause: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382107/whats-a-good-way-to-extend-error-in-javascript/69365658#69365658

Answer (score 16):

**2022 update:** Thanks to a TC39 proposal, it's now possible to specify error cause in javascript, like this:

```
try {
  operation();
} catch (error) {
  throw new Error("An error has occurred while doing operation", { cause: error });
}
```

feature available on plateforms: Node.js (16.9+), Chrome (93+), Firefox (91+) and Safari (15+)

I wrote a more detailed article [here](https://medium.com/ovrsea/power-up-your-node-js-debugging-and-error-handling-with-the-new-error-cause-feature-4136c563126a) ;)

Comment: To enable this feature in your node project add `"compilerOptions": { "lib": ["es2022"]...` to your `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing is to look inside the error stack, it gives you information about how (by which path) it reached to that error. You can add additional properties/information manually when throwing the error as well. Otherwise you can use some profiling/monitoring tools if you need more information: Clinic.js, node.js standard profiling, etc.