# Typescript compile issue (error TS2705 - ES2015 --lib option)

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules, tsconfig

When compiling a typescript file with `tsc -p .` I'm getting the following error

> error TS2705: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the
> 'Promise' constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the
> 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your '--lib' option.
>
> 9 async function fetchImages(param1: string): Promise<string[]> {

Compiling with the lib option `tsc --lib es5` doesn't solve it

Could could someone explain a bit more about the --lib option and how this would fix it as it didn't in my case.

```
node -v
v19.9.0

tsc -v                    
Version 5.1.0-dev.20230512
```

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig to read more about this file */

    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es5",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */

    /* Modules */
    "module": "es6",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    "rootDir": ".",                                  /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */
    "baseUrl": ".",                                  /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */

    /* Emit */
    "sourceMap": true,                                /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */
    "outDir": "dist",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */

    /* Interop Constraints */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    
    /* Completeness */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @JeffreyMixon just did, thanks for looking at this question

Comment: @JeffreyMixon as you can see I already had the target set to es5... so not sure why the lib option (tsc --lib es5 script.ts) would help

Comment: `"es5"` is not an appropriate [`target`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target) for Node v19.x. [These](https://github.com/tsconfig/bases/blob/main/bases/node19.json) are the suggested base compilation settings. Read over [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73394582/438273) for more context — your question deals with the same exact compiler environment concerns — it's just that it's not specifically about the `Error` class.

Comment: I think it's appropriate to close this question as a duplicate, but since you created a bounty, that's not possible at the moment...

Comment: @jsejcksn perfect, thanks for looking it up - I could mark it as duplicate if that's appropriate indeed - it's been a while since I contributed to stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has already been mentioned, your `tsconfig.json` settings are not really appropriate for a Node 19 project (and possibly for a Node project in general)...

However, your issue is a bit more nuanced to be precise. Consider the following:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src/",
    "listFiles": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "es5",
  },
}
```

```
async function doWork() : Promise<string[]> {
    return null;
}
```

```bash
$ tsc
index.ts:1:27 - error TS2705: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your '--lib' option.

1 async function doWork() : Promise<string[]> {
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The exact reason for this is that native `Promise` support was not introduced until `ES6` aka `ES2015`, not `ES5`, despite `async` being available.

Try removing the return type from the function:

```
async function doWork()  {
    return ["a", "b", "c"]
}
```

Interestingly, this code will compile. If you look at the transpiled JS, it looks like this:

```js
function doWork() {
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function () {
        return __generator(this, function (_a) {
            return [2 /*return*/, ["a", "b", "c"]];
        });
    });
}
```

The compiler is shimming both the `awaiter` and `generators` which are also not available until `ES6`. Note there is no `Promise` or `Generator` type here.

Changing your `target` to `es6` where native Promise support was added resolves the issue. The transpiled JS looks like this:

```js
function doWork() {
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
        return ["a", "b", "c"];
    });
}
```

You can see the native `Generator` (`function*`) being emitted here.

In summary, you are targeting `ES5` which does not have native `Promise` support, hence the errors using that type. The solution is to either provide a `Promise`-compatible implementation or use `ES6`.

However, if you are really writing a Node 19 application, you should probably use the completely different compiler options regardless.