# Creating a ts-node Esm project. Error: Unknown file extension ".ts"

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules, ts-node

I'm trying to create a barebones repo that sets up a project using ts-node and ESM. This question has been asked, but there are several out of date answers- and even recent answers seem to have issues such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76725253/ts-node-and-esm-unknown-file-extension-ts)

I've created a `src/index.ts` file that I am trying to run:

`src/index.ts`

```js
console.log('hi');
```

Here is my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "coolProjName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc",
    "dev": "ts-node --esm src/index.ts"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```

And my tsconfigs:

`tsconfig.node20.json`

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Node 20",
  "_version": "20.1.0",

  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ES2022"],
    "module": "Node16",
    "target": "es2022",

    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node16"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.node20.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "esnext",
      "outDir": "./dist",
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

I've followed every recommendation I can find, but `npm run dev` results in:

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"

for my index.ts file. How can I resolve this?

Node version - 20.4.0

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74608156/5232058), using `tsx` instead of `ts-node` will solve the problem.

```
npm i -D tsx
npx tsx src/index.ts
```

Answer (score -1):

> Remove "type": "module" from package.json
>
> If you don't want to remove "type": "module" (for example if you're using import statements in your .ts which allows the inference of types from modules), then you can use the following option in tsconfig.json:
>
> ```json
> {
>  "compilerOptions": {
>    "esModuleInterop": true,
>  }
> }
> ```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62096269/cant-run-my-node-js-typescript-project-typeerror-err-unknown-file-extension)

Comment: - nvm wrong question