# How to specify a "caused by" in a JavaScript Error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stack-trace

In my NodeJS program, I parse some user JSON file.

So I use :

```
this.config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path));
```

The problem is that if the json file is not correctly formated, the error thrown is like:

```
undefined:55
            },
            ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
    at Object.parse (native)
    at new MyApp (/path/to/docker/lib/node_modules/myApp/lib/my-app.js:30:28)
...
```

As it is not really user friendly I would like to throw an `Error` specifying some user friendly message (like "your config file is not well formated") but I want to keep the stacktrace in order to point to the problematic line.

In the Java world I used `throw new Exception("My user friendly message", catchedException)` in order to have the original exception which caused that one.

How is it possible in the JS world?

Comment: Wrap it in `try{}catch(){}` and create your own message.

Comment: Yes this is how I wanted to do at first. But I wanted to keep the original stack also, which contains the original message pointing to the problematic line (in my example)... And I can't find a "good" way to do that in the JS error handling I saw until now on the web...

Comment: I actually see that my question is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886769/how-to-chain-exceptions-in-javascript-ie-add-cause-like-in-java

Comment: Node.js now supports adding specific cause of the error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382107/whats-a-good-way-to-extend-error-in-javascript/69365658#69365658

Answer (score 39, accepted):

What I finally did is:

```js
try {
    this.config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path));
} catch(err) {
    var newErr = new Error('Problem while reading the JSON file');
    newErr.stack += '\nCaused by: '+err.stack;
    throw newErr;
}
```

Comment: And yet the ["primary source"](https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors) regarding best practices mentions not to touch the "stack" property at all. In java there's a "cause" property.  Do nodejs people expect that to be set?

Comment: A better answer would be something that only calculates the stack when it is read. Something like Object.defineProperty(newErr, 'stack', {get: function() { return ??? + '\nCaused by: ' + err.stack } }). But barring that, this seems pretty nice to me.

Comment: I assume the last line should be:
    `throw newErr;`

Comment: this is what i was looking for thanks. This is a clear example of what to do when you have a custom stack trace and you are throwing an error from a controlled situation (ie when a library provides you a with a stacktrace without an error)

Answer (score 10):

There is an new Error Cause proposal for ECMAScript, and it reached stage-4 at TC34!

It means it will be in the next ECMAScript version!

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-error-cause

You would provide the cause as an error option:

```
throw new Error(`Couldn't parse file at path ${filePath}`, { cause: err });
```

The ES proposal only formalize it on the language level, but browsers/NodeJS should normally agree to log the full causal chain in practice (see https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/38725)

---

As of today (end of 2021), Firefox Devtools are already able to log nested stacktraces!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Joyent released a Node.js package that can be used exactly for that. It is called [VError](https://github.com/joyent/node-verror). I paste an example of how you would use the pacakge:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var filename = '/nonexistent';
fs.stat(filename, function (err1) {
    var err2 = new VError(err1, 'stat "%s"', filename);
    console.error(err2.message);
});
```

would print the following:

```
stat "/nonexistent": ENOENT, stat '/nonexistent'
```

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to [multiple questions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40287580). Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Comment: [@netflix/nerror](https://github.com/Netflix/nerror) is a more modern alternative to verror and has built-in types.

Answer (score 0):

2021 Update: To chain exceptions in JS:

```
class MyAppError extends Error {
    constructor(...params) {
        super(...params)
        if (Error.captureStackTrace) {
            // This is the key line!
            Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
        }
        this.name = this.constructor.name
    }
}
```

See the Mozilla docs on  [Error.captureStackTrace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)

Comment: This is not standard, it's a specific V8 function.

Answer (score -4):

Use a [`try / catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) block:

```
try {
    this.config = JSON.parse("}}junkJSON}");
    //...etc
}
catch (e) {
    //console.log(e.message);//the original error message 
    e.message = "Your config file is not well formatted.";//replace with new custom message
    console.error(e);//raise the exception in the console
    //or re-throw it without catching
    throw e;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0ogf1jxs/5/

**UPDATE:** If you really feel the need for a custom error you can define your own:

```
function BadConfig(message) {
   this.message = message;
   this.name = "BadConfig";
}
BadConfig.prototype = new Error();
BadConfig.prototype.constructor = BadConfig;

try {
    this.config = JSON.parse("}}badJson}");
} catch(e) {
    throw new BadConfig("Your JSON is wack!");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kL394boo/

Lots of useful info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Comment: I wanted to "throw" something because I'm in library code, so I want the developer who uses it to be able to catch it and display it to the user in the way he wants... Actually I want to do something like passing the root cause to a new Exception in Java

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783818/how-do-i-create-a-custom-error-in-javascript

Comment: Just edit this one and change e.message to your user friendly message and throw e

Comment: @JonasLiljestrand - Updated answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it still doesn't reply to my question which is: how to chain exceptions in JS like adding cause to an Exception in Java. Your `BadConfig` class doesn't include the catched `e` and can't display it as a cause in the error log if the one who catch the `BadConfig` output it in `console.error`.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding your requirements. The `stack` is still available. See test here: http://jsfiddle.net/kL394boo/1/